# Photos showing growth - ideas?

Tags: toddler, growth

I've been taking monthly pictures of baby in his crib each month with a certain teddy bear from 0-12 months.  He's at 13 months now and I'd like to keep up the monthly teddy bear pictures, but he's already getting big to photograph in the crib.  Does anyone have any creative ideas for monthly pics from 13-24 months, preferably including the teddy bear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a fantastic idea to have recurring photos of the kids where the location remains the same. Especially in the first 2 years, changes happen so fast... I have lots of photos but I have neglected the opportunity you mention.

At this age, your son can probably sit still for a few moments, so you should be able to sit him somewhere and snap a picture within a few seconds. (Caveat: my toddler is nuclear-powered and will not sit still for any number of seconds. I'm thinking he's a statistical outlier so this should not be a problem for you.)

As for locations, if you have a house or a garden it would be interesting to see the changes in season and, if you keep it up long, even the changes over the years. Friends of mine do make photos twice a year with all the kids sitting on a big rock in their garden, or standing next to a tree. You can really see how kids AND nature grows in those pictures.

If you don't have a house/garden (I don't), then pick a memorable location in your home, e.g. in the middle of the living room. Or pick an outdoor location, e.g. standing in front of the family car.

Comment: I have a nuclear one too.  It does make photos a little harder.

Comment: I did decide to go for outdoor pictures, especially appropriate with my little adventurer.  I've taken pictures on a little tricicle for 13, 14, and 15 months so far, with 16 months coming up soon.  It shows his growth and development of balance and other skills as learns to use the trike.

Answer (score 1):

Does he have a favorite blanket or quilt to lie on and be photographed from above while the bears lies next to him? It would be obvious he's not standing up, of course, but if the blanket is his must-have companion then it's nice to have in the picture anyway.

An alternative is to find a picture of you from your childhood are replicate it. My mother-in-law was photographed in a particular dress as a very young girl, and then they repeated that picture of my wife. We, in turn, found the dress and took the very same pose of both of our daughters, and the combination of pictures is pretty fantastic. The more pictures of yourself that you could find to duplicate the better.

Comment: What an awesome idea to use the parents' childhood clothes!

Answer (score 0):

My wife is a photographer, and she had tried something similar to this.  We had the baby propped up on a sofa between two teddy bears.  This wasn't working so we took a shelf off the wall and lay the teddy and baby on their backs then took the photos from above.

If you look carefully at the photos you can see what was done, but it has produced a really nice and repeatable result.

Hope that helps.